# Query in LINQ TO SQL not inserting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've created a simple query in adding users in the database but there error is that the data is not showing. here's my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath))
            {

                //Instantiate a new Hasher Object
                var hasher = new Hasher();

                hasher.SaltSize = 16;

                //Encrypts The password
                var encryptedPassword = hasher.Encrypt(txtPass.Text);

                Account newUser = new Account();

                newUser.accnt_User = txtUser.Text;
                newUser.accnt_Position = txtPosition.Text;


                // Replace AccountTableName with the actual table
                // name found in your dbml's context
                myDbContext.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
                myDbContext.SubmitChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("XD");
            }
        }
```

And My Table data  shows only this

[image]

Comment: just asking, have you closed the dialog which shows the table data and refreshed the page and checked again?

Comment: You're setting the Position twice.  The second should probably be the password.  Typo?

Comment: How do I insert the encrypted password? it gave me an error that it cannot be converted to a string

Comment: Did you update the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `InsertOnSubmit` directly on the context:

**Edit:** Using statement added. Reminder courtesy of [@David Khaykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546000/david-khaykin)

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath))
{

    //Instantiate a new Hasher Object
    var hasher = new Hasher();

    hasher.SaltSize = 16;

    //Encrypts The password
    var encryptedPassword = hasher.Encrypt(txtPass.Text);

    Account newUser = new Account();

    newUser.accnt_User = txtUser.Text;
    newUser.accnt_Position = txtPosition.Text;
    newUser.accnt_Position = encryptedPassword;

    // Replace AccountTableName with the actual table
    // name found in your dbml's context
    myDbContext.AccountTableName.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
    myDbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Exactly correct - and @user962206, I would recommend wrapping the whole thing in a using {} statement; i.e., using (DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath)) { // your code }

Comment: @David Khaykin it gave me this error Error 2 'PAS.DataClasses1DataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Context' and no extension method 'Context' accepting a first argument of type 'PAS.DataClasses1DataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PAS\PAS\AddUserWindow.cs 51 25 PAS

Comment: @user962206: Check the DBML file and make sure the "accounts" table is included; if it is not found in the context, it means the DBML file doesn't contain that table.

Comment: @user962206 that is correct, DataClasses1DataContext does not contain a property called context; the "context" is the name of the variable that represents your DataClasses1DataContext, in your example, it is "myDbContext"; so if the table name is accounts, and your variable is called myDbContext, then you write myDbContext.accounts.InsertOnSubmit(newUser); myDbContext.SubmitChanges() - just like shown in this answer.

Comment: @David Khaykin: +1 on the using statment. In fact I'm going to edit to incorporate.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin does it go something like this? [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Accounts")]
 public partial class Account : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @user962206 yes that's it! So in this case, you have a table (class which represents the table) called Account. Your DataClasses1DataContext (represented by myDbContext variable) therefore contains a property called Account. Just plug it in as myDbContext.Account.InsertOnSubmit(newUser) and you're good to go. Does this make sense?

Comment: @user962206 maybe you can post an edit with your updated code because at this point it's difficult to see/imagine what you are doing and where it's going wrong :)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin There Done but it is still not working, see the code I posted above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8194/discussion-between-david-khaykin-and-user962206)